# I have an issue on making register system

Tags: python, json

I'm currently making a register system in Python. It did work. It appends new data ever time it inputs. But I want to make it so it denied the register process if there's an existing data. Either from the unique id, or the username. Here are my codes.

```py
# The data input from client
uniqueid = input("Please write the desired uniqueid : ")
os.system("cls")
name = input("Write your desired username : ")
os.system("cls")

# Loading up json file
with open("uniqueid.json") as fp:
    jsondata = json.load(fp)

# Appending data file
jsondata.append({
        "uniqueid" : uniqueid,
        "Name" : name,
        "Permission level" : "1"
    })

# Dumping the data
with open("uniqueid.json", 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(jsondata, json_file, 
                        indent=4,  
                        separators=(',',': '))
```

Comment: your code doesn't contain the check(i suppose you need `if` statement)

Comment: I know. I haven't add it yet because I didn't know what to add in the `if` statement

Comment: read the file as json(dict), and check the json.

Comment: Can you send it as code example and send it using answer instead of comment?

Comment: can you try my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several flaws in your code but here I just show one possible way to check if user with the `uniqueid` is already registered.

```py
with open("uniqueid.json") as fp:
    jsondata = json.load(fp)
    # you can use same syntax to check Name if you want
    if any(x for x in jsondata if x['uniqueid'] == uniqueid):
        print(f'user with {uniqueid} already registered, so denied')
        exit(0) # stop the following code execution
```

Comment: `return` can only be used in a function.

Comment: then use `exit(0)`?